# Git repo within git repo - but both not connected/dependant to each other

Tags: git

I have a hardware electronics project that I maintain with git but it doesn't actually contain any "programming contents" in that sense. I just keep track of my own work and it's all text file based, so git is a very convenient way for me to work.

Nevertheless there is some coding involved but I am not the programmer. Right now the programmer has a git for himself too - just as I do. But this way the project is divided over two computers and one dropbox.

It would be great if I could just copy his git folder into the main project folder that is my git. I read though that if I do it this way, the files in his folder will simply get ignored. Submodules seem a bit complicated for what we do and the whole subtree ordeal also isn't the simplest of solutions somehow.

My ideal situation would be if I could just continue working on the project with my git, have his git within my folders and see his commits everytime he makes them. He just keeps continuing using his git within another folder structure then. I don't need to touch his files, read them or exchange anything from the parent to the child git. The idea is to have everything in one place.

What is the best solution for us?

Comment: do you mean to use `git submodules`?

Comment: Subtree or submodule are your only choices. Subtrees are easier in my opinion.